# GridBagLayout or BorderLayout for proposed project in Swing/AWT?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I'm attempting to create a GUI as pictured:

[image]

I'm having some trouble deciding which layout would be the best for this.

I've attempted to use a `GridBagLayout`, but can't figure out how to make items different sizes, and how to position them.

I've also considered using a `BorderLayout` and creating an `eastpanel`, `westpanel` and `centerpanel` these using the respective layout constraints to put them there, but this feels incorrect.

I've also read the how to use `GridBagLayout` Java tutorial, but still can't figure out how to achieve the goal.

Comment: is your frame resizable ?

Comment: if not, you can check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: The Frame needs to be resizable sadly, what's the best layout to use?

Comment: hum, GridBagLayout seems to be the best, but could be tricky. Have you tried MigLayout ? http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: @Mead *"if not (resizable), you can check this (using no layout)"* No, even then, correctly positioning components requires a layout strategy. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not force yourself to use only a single panel with a single layout. Nest several panels inside each other with each panel possibly having different layouts.

You could have 1 root panel with a BorderLayout. For the top you have a panel with a FlowLayout (or maybe a gridbaglayout). And the center can be another panel with a GridBagLayout or perhaps a combination of more nested panels.

There is no one magic layout that can do everything. Composition is the key.

Comment: See also this example of [combining layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).